# How to highlight line numbers on number keys pressing in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting, neovim

For example in relativenumber mode when pressing 1, line numbers 1 above 1 below and line 11 need to highlighted:

11 <
 10
  9
  8
  7
  6
  5
  4
  3
  2
  1 <
  0  simple text
  1 <
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8

Or any other lines that contains 1.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number column is entirely controlled by the respective `'number'` and `'relativenumber'` setttings. You can influence the number alignment and highlighting, but what you want is not possible. With a plugin, you'd have to completely (and slowly) emulate the number column. It would be better to implement this directly in Vim's C source code. However, unless you provide a strong motivation for the usefulness of that feature (and to be honest I don't see that here at all), it's unlikely to be accepted into the mainline code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I switched my strategy for vim navigation so this feature doesn't seems like be very useful if it hard to implement.